# Outputting video to a window with rounded corners in PySide6

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt-designer, pyside6

When creating a graphical interface using QT Designer and the PySide6 library, I needed to output video to one of the interface windows created in QT Designer as QVideoWidget. Here is a program snippet that successfully performs this function:

```
def play_video(self):
    global player,screen
    audio = QAudioOutput(video_widget)
    player = QMediaPlayer(video_widget)
    screen = QVideoWidget(video_widget) 
    video_widget.setGeometry(150, 610, 495, 287) 
    video_widget.setStyleSheet(scr_style)
    player.setAudioOutput(audio)
    player.setVideoOutput(screen)
    player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile('demo.mp4'))
    screen.show()
    player.play()
```

But in order for the interface to turn out beautiful, it is necessary that the video is displayed on the screen with rounded corners.
All attempts to influence the shape of the "screen" or to overlay a rounded border on top of the video have not been successful.

Neither the .raise_() methods nor the .setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) flags help.
In all cases "screen" with rectangular corners appeared above all windows and drawings. Is there a solution to this problem?